# Makefile "No rule to make target" error in mac os

Tags: java, makefile

I have the following directory:

[image]

And I get the the following error when running `make` from lab01.

`No rule to make target 'student/Student.java', needed by 'student/Student.class'.  Stop.`

The Human.class file is created, but then the error appears.

This is my makefile:

```
make: Human.class student/Student.class teacher/Teacher.class Lab01.class

Lab01.class: Lab01.java
    javac Lab01.java

teacher/Teacher.class: teacher/Teacher.java
    javac teacher/Teacher.java

student/Student.class: student/Student.java
    javac student/Student.java

Human.class: Human.java
    javac Human.java

clean:
    del Lab01.class
    del teacher/Teacher.class
    del student/Student.class
    del Human.class
```

I have never used makefiles before, so I am not sure about what can be causing the error. Any ideas? I'm using mac os x, if that matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the command from the `lab001` directory.

The path `student/Student.java` isn't valid from that location.

You either need to move the makefile to the toplevel directory (and add `lab001` to the `Human.java` and `Human.class` entries) or use `../student/Student.java` and `../student/Student.class`.

There are plenty of other things that could be done to improve this makefile as well but those are the root of your problem.

Comment: Or he could leave the makefile where it is, but run Make from the top directory (and add `lab01/` in a couple of places). I'm not recommending this, it's just an option.

Comment: I haven't worked this all through but I believe that would require the same modifications as if he moved the makefile to the toplevel (since essentially all we are talking about is changing PWD for the make process) and just means they would need to run `make -f lab001/Makefile` instead of just `make`. But yes, I suppose that would work.